# Change to PostgreSQL raise django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table Error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite, heroku

I was developing with default DB SQLite for a Django project but now I need to deploy to Heroku so I switched to PostgreSQL. However, during the deployment, I kept getting `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table:` error:

#### full error in `heroku logs --tail`:

```
2019-02-08T13:56:10.598144+00:00 app[web.1]: Internal Server Error: /catelogue/floor
2019-02-08T13:56:10.598152+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-02-08T13:56:10.598154+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
2019-02-08T13:56:10.598156+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
2019-02-08T13:56:10.598158+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 296, in execute
2019-02-08T13:56:10.598160+00:00 app[web.1]: return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
2019-02-08T13:56:10.598162+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: product_floor
```

As you can see, there should be a table called **product_floor** in SQLite.

But the problem is, I have already updated my db configuration to PostgreSQL and deleted SQLite3 file in my project folder. I also deleted all migration files and cached files and ran `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` again.

When I turned `DEBUG` to true and access pages in the local browser, there's no problem. But when I access certain pages served in URL `*.herokuapp.com/product/*`(pages that use data from database), I got `Server Error 500`.

#### My `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone

class Floor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='floor name')
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='floor',
        blank=True,
        editable=True,
        verbose_name='floor image'
    )
    image_height = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False, default="340")
    image_width = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True, editable=False, default="340")
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name='floor description')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='floor price')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'product'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
### Add some classes with almost same fields
```

#### My `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '[DB NAME]',
        'USER': '[DB USER]',
        'PASSWORD': '[***]',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Show the rest of that traceback. Most likely, something is trying to do a db query on import, before the migrations can run.

Comment: From your heroku logs we can see that it is not switched to postgresql and tries to use sqlite settings. How you managed and deployed the last version with a postgresql settings?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thx. I just updated the question.

Comment: @EminMastizada I directly deleted SQLite file in root folder(also use command to remove installed sqlitedb) && changed db config in `settings.py` to what stated in question && create database using `sudo -u postgres psql` && grant user all privileges && then clean the cache and migrations in the app && run project locally(changed from dev setting but ofcoz I changed it back before deploy to Heroku again) to re-upload img and files thru admin center && run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` again.

Comment: No it's the bit before that we need. The traceback doesn't begin with `return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)`; where is the start?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Sorry for the confusion. I updated the question again.

Comment: All I can tell from these info is that the settings are not changed as the error is directly coming from the sqlite: "sqlite3.OperationalError". It should come from the psycopg2 for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer. It seemed that I made a minor change to the db model, so after both `migrate` / `makemigrations` locally, it's suggested to run `migrate` again after deployment. Thank you all for the suggestions.